# duplicate ID mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
coordinatesCollection.findOne({
                "unique_id": unique_id,
            }, function(err, object) {
                if (object) {
                    coordinatesCollection.update({
                        "unique_id": unique_id
                    }, {
                        $push: {
                            coordinates: {
                                "coordinateX": msg.coordinatex,
                                "coordinateY": msg.coordinatey,
                                "ms_time": ms_time,
                                "page": msg.page,
                            }
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    coordinatesCollection.insert({
                        "unique_id": unique_id,
                        "coordinates": [{
                            "coordinateX": msg.coordinatex,
                            "coordinateY": msg.coordinatey,
                            "ms_time": ms_time,
                            "page": msg.page,
                        }]
                    })
                }
            });
        });
```

The objective of this code is: If unique_id exists add coordinateX, coordinateY, ms_time and page to coordinates arrays if not exists insert unique_id and new array to coordinates.
When I saw the collection I found multiple documents with the same unique_id.
What is wrong ?

Comment: You mean `coordinatesCollection.insert` is called everytime?

Answer (score 0):

For this problem I suggest You to use instead only update function with `$exists` statement in query.